# No trabajan funciones de *.gs en *.html (google script)

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Tengo un .html del que quiero obtener las funciones de un .gs

No sé la manera correcta de obtener esas funciones. Creo que están bien puestas pero aun así no me funcionan correctamente, ya que no hacen nada.

Aquí dejo mi código HTML:

```
<html>
  
  <head>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

    
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function cerrarVentanaModal(){
          google.script.host.close();
          
      } 
      
      function procesaFormulario(){
        var formularioPrincipal = document.datosDispositivo;
        google.script.run.procesaFormDatosDispositivo(formularioPrincipal);
        
        //google.script.host.close();  SI LO QUEREMOS CERRAR DESPUES DE GUARDAR
        
      }

      function buscaInformacion(){
        
        google.script.run.buscar(document.forms[0]);
        
      }

      function verificacionMinima(){

        google.script.run.prueba();


      }

          
      $(function() {
          $("#cancelar").click(cerrarVentanaModal);
          $("#guardar").click(procesaFormulario);
          $("#busqueda").click(buscaInformacion);
          $("#modificar").click(verificacionMinima);
      });
          
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>


etcetera...
```

y aquí mi código del .GS:

```
//FUNCION PARA MOSTRAR FORMULARIO
function mostrarFormulario() {
  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html').evaluate()
     .setWidth(700)
     .setHeight(700);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html,'INVENTARIO CAR GETAFE'); 
  

}

//FUNCION PARA GUARDAR FORMULARIO
function procesaFormDatosDispositivo(e){
  
  var sNOMBRE = e.NOMBRE;
  var sSERIE = e.SERIE;
  var sDISPOSITIVO = e.DISPOSITIVO;
  var sSECCION = e.SECCION;
  var sPROCESO = e.PROCESO;
  var sESTADO = e.ESTADO;
  
  var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('BASE DE DATOS');
  var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();
  
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1, 1).setValue("XXXX");
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1, 3).setValue(sNOMBRE);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1, 4).setValue(sSERIE);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1, 5).setValue(sDISPOSITIVO);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1, 11).setValue(sSECCION);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1, 6).setValue(sPROCESO);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1, 12).setValue(sESTADO);
  Logger.log(ultimaFila);
}
```

Ya no sé qué más puede fallar. No sé si es la importación del script jQuery(he probado versiones 1 y 2...) o un error al llamar a las funciones del .gs desde el html...

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberías incluir un [mcve] (el código no está completo pues ha se ha se cerrado las etiquetas body y html, en otras palabras nos debes poner etc.), incluyendo los mensajes textuales de error tanto en la página de ejecuciones como en la consola del navegador.

Comment: Es probable que el problema se deba a `document.datosDispositivo` ya que `datosDipositivo` no es un atributo estándar `document`